# nginx - transform absolute urls to relative

Tags: nginx, proxy, server, torrent

## Here's the situation:

I'm running a Deluge (Torrent Client) server listening on `<server>:1337` and I have a website `example.com`.

What I've actually done, and this is what I want, is made nginx proxy all request to `<server>:1337` once I reach `example.com/torrent-ui`.

## And here's the problem:

Deluge uses absolute url, e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/gettext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ext-base.js"></script>
```

Which is interpreted by the navigator as `example.com/gettext.js`, so I want a way to make these urls point to the right thing.. e.g: `example.com/torrent-ui/gettext.js`.

How can I do it?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Configure deluge. Or use subdomain

Comment: @AlexeyTen yeah, I started Deluge server within another base, Thanks ! ^^